# How to use OG meta tags for Pinterest share

Tags: facebook-opengraph, pinterest

I have an application and i am using Pinterest share in my site. For sharing title i am using og meta-tag like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="ABC SCHOOL2">
```

Now i want to share description. please tell me which og mata tag is used for description?

Comment: Errrm, `og:description`? http://ogp.me/

Comment: I had tried this meta tag. but Pinterest pick og:title for description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this official documentation from Pinterest https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins/

from my test just now. meta description works fine

```
 <meta name="description" content="4 Pics, 1 Word Tagalog" />
```

Try to view source my page (copy paste following in your browser location):

```
view-source:http://fedmich.com/android-games/4-pics-1-word-tagalog/
```

Comment: Post the code, man; this is useless if you updated your external website, which looks like you did!

Comment: @LoydChristmas is your downvote really necessary?  The code is there, <meta name="description" content="XXXXX" />

Comment: Note that your HTML source is compressed. Not really easy to read the original. From Firebug, though, it looks good.

Comment: Link to Pinterest documentation is out of date, more helpful guide here: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/rich-pins/. Think you need to apply to have rich pins show up now.